# SOCKET.IO - console.log is printing desired output but not io.emit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to stream output from command line to html webpage.

SERVER:

```
  var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    const { spawn } = require("child_process");
    const ls = spawn("mycommand", ['-l 500'], {shell: true});
    
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
    
    
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        ls.stdout.on("data", data => {
        io.emit(`${data}`, msg);
    });
      });
    });
    
    
    http.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('listening on *:3000');
    });
```

CLIENT:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: 0.5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>



<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting output on my HTML page when using **io.emit()** in my SERVER code but if I instead use **console.log()** desired output is printed on my command console but not on HTML. Where is the bug that is not allowing me to display output on my HTML?

My objective is for server to stream output to the client from command line when user submits message to the server.

Comment: Your statement `io.emit(\`${data}\`, msg);` is going to emit a message name that varies based on the value of `data` which your client will not have a listener for so it will never see that message.  The client code only shows a listener for a `chat message` so if you want that client code to receive your message, you would have to send `io.emit('chat message', data)`, but I'm not entirely sure that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's also unclear what you want the server to do with the `$('#m').val()` that you are sending it when the client does this: `socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());`

Comment: This server code also has a problem that EVERY time it receives the `chat message` message, it adds yet another listener here:  `ls.stdout.on("data", data => { ...});` which will cause those listeners to accumulate and duplicate handlers to be in place which will create problems.

Comment: Also, your server code issues the spawn command when the server starts, puts no listeners on it initially and then never communicates with it again.  Unless it is spewing data continuously, it's unclear how the client could start getting data from it at exactly the right time and the listener that is attached for that client is never removed.  This can't be correct.

Comment: I haven't written an answer here because I can see a bunch of things wrong, but I don't know what you're actually trying to accomplish with the spawned process so I don't know what code to recommend.  The desired objective of this code is not clear to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for pointing out many wrong things in my code. To make it clear my objective is for server to stream command line output to the client from when user submits message to the server.

Comment: Still lots of open questions.  Is the client supposed to be sending commands to the command line?  You don't show any code that does that.  What is the server supposed to do with the data that comes with the `chat message` incoming message?

Comment: @jfriend00 client just needs to send any text message to the server, so that it can begin receiving the output stream

Comment: Is the output stream continuously flowing data and the client wants to just start listening to that stream of data?  Or does it create data only in response to some input from the client?

Comment: @jfriend00 It is a continuously flowing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can start listening to the stream on behalf of one particular client when it receives a chat message like this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    function listener(data) {
        // send data from ls back to cilent
        socket.emit('lsdata', data);
    }
    ls.stdout.on('data', listener);
  });
  // when socket disconnects, remove the listener
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    ls.stdout.off('data', listener);
  });
});
```

Then, the client code needs a listener for the `lsdata` event:

```
socket.on('lsdata', function(msg){
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
```

Note, there are still lots of your requirements that are unclear here because this starts listening on any chat message and will create duplicate listeners if it receives multiple chat messages from the same client (which does not seem right - but it's not clear how you want that to work).  It seems more like the client should send a `'startListening'` message and then maybe also have a `'stopListening'` message it could send if it wanted to unplug from the data stream.

Comment: I would like to avoid creating duplicate listeners. Could you clarify on how to send 'startListening'/'stopListening' messages with client?

Comment: @MeditaInc. - You just send a `startListening` message from client to server on socket.io and start listening to the `ls` process on that message instead of on the `chat message` process.  Similarly, you could (if you need to) send a `stopListening` message from client to server and stop listening to the `ls` process on that message.  Then, when your client sends `chat message`, you do whatever else you want to do on that message.